# Change Background Color based on innerText?

Tags: php, css, html-table, background-color, import-from-csv

I'm very new to PHP and I'm not sure how to go about this.  I have a super large CSV file that is loaded as an html table using fget.  How can I go through a specific column and change td background color of only the specific cells of that column that contain the word "Yes" to green?

For reference, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("market_research.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
            if (substr($cell, 0,4) == "http") {
                echo "<td>" ."<a href='" . $cell . "'>Go!</a>";
            } else
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell);
        }
        echo "<tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";


?>
```

Here is my current CSS:

```
tr {background-color: #f7f7f7;}
body {background-color:#8b9dc3;}
td:first-child { 
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
}

td:nth-child(odd)
{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr:first-child {
        background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 110%;
        height: 50px;
}

td {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Will 'Yes'  be in any cell (td) & is it Just 'Yes' as whole string?

Comment: Are you familiar  with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Can you show how that `p` goes in your `td`? i mean a simple prototype, is it only containing `p` or anything else you have inside `td`?

Comment: That p was in there from something else-I just edited it.  "Yes" could  appear as part of a string in any column, but I want to target any instances of it within one specific column (where it is the entire string).  I have some experience with javascript and jquery (although more than I do with php)-I'm in the process of teaching myself that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it like this:

Hope this will help you

You need to add `data-attr` to your element `<p>` while Generating `<td>`s using `fget()`

```
<p data-val="Yes">Yes</p>
```

and your css would be like this:

```
p[data-val="Yes"] {background-color:green;}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ScLZs/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a class for these cells. This identifies a group then you can style these in your stylesheet or  tags.

Add an additional IF statement that checks for your condition "$cell contain 'yes'"

You can check for a string in a string like this, this example $a is your variable and you are checking for string 'mattiscool' - if it finds it then it will output 'true'

if (strpos($a,'mattiscool') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}

Instead we want to output your TD cell plus a class tag.
So add part of your if statement print inside the  tags - like so

```
<td Class="myfirstclass">
```

Then in your stylesheet add the styling for this class - for example.

```
myfirstclass{
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:16pt;
}
```

This what you were looking for?